# Custom Formik validation for input text field based on onBlur of other field

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have text field called A which is not mandatory. If user enters some value to A field and trying to without entering any value to B field which is dependent on A field, a validation message should be fired.

```
   <Field.Input
            name={field.name}
            error={Boolean(validationMessage)}
            defaultValue={field.value}
            onBlur={(e) => {
              field.name === 'Name'
                ? e.target.value
                  ? (form.setFieldValue(field.name, error),
                    form.setFieldTouched(field.name))
                  : (form.setFieldValue(field.name, e.target.value), form.setFieldTouched(field.name))
                : form.setFieldValue(field.name, e.target.value)
              form.setFieldTouched(field.name)
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the validation in `onFocus` of Field B.

```js
<Field
    name="fieldB"
    validate={() => {
        if (!values.fieldA) return 'Please fill fieldA';
    }}
    onFocus={() => validateField('fieldB')}
/>
```

More details on validation including the usage of `validate` and `validateField` can be found in [Formik Documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation).

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zzpnzw8p3

*Note:* Additionally, you can also disable Field B if Field A is empty.

```js
<Field
    name="fieldB"
    disabled={!values.fieldA}
    placeholder={!values.fieldA && 'Please fill fieldA'}
    ...
/>
```